# IOS jQuery plugin to webview

Tags: ios

i have downloaded a  ganttChart library from here
(https://github.com/thegrubbsian/jquery.ganttView) and added to my application after that i have created a html file like this

```
      <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
       "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
      <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <head>
         <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>TITLE</title>
      <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.js"> 
      </script>
         <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.8.4.js">
      </script>
           <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ganttView.js"></script>
          <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="date.js"></script>
          <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="data.js"></script>
         <link type="text/css" href="jquery.ganttView.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
     </head>
      <body>
          <div id="Pluginwrapper">

             <div id="Plugincontainer"></div>    
         </div>
     </body>
   </html>
```

then i am loading this html file via webview like this

```
   [webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle 
    mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sample" ofType:@"html"] isDirectory:NO]]];
```

but webview doesn't show anything. please tell what i am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The web view doesn't show anything because you haven't added any visible content to the page, just markup.

If you're looking for your plugin to generate you some output, you should look at it's [example files](https://github.com/thegrubbsian/jquery.ganttView/blob/master/example/index.html).

Comment: i have just added the code in my html file but its still doesn't show anything.